# PKIX path building failure with trusted certificate and all Trusting manage

Tags: java, ssl, testng, web-api-testing

thanks in advance for the help.

I developed a suite of api tests in Java TestNG against an api deployed to a non-secure internal QA environment.  Recently this application was re-deployed to a new, secure environment.  When this happened I began to see the following error on every api request, both GET and POST:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My first move was to install the appropriate certificate, even though it is signed by DigiCert, so it should be approved by default.

```
keytool -import -alias ca -file qa4cert.crt -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

And that had no effect.  I also tried adding the certificate via the IDE (Intellij).  Again, no effect, still seeing the same error.

Since I was unable to make progress here, and I am still working against an internal QA environment with no sensitive data, I was comfortable dropping the certificate validation and install an all-trusting cert manager.  My simple implementation is below:

```
package test_utils;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class SSLTool {

    private static boolean isTrustAllCertsInitialized = false;

    public static void disableCertificateValidation() {

        if (isTrustAllCertsInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        isTrustAllCertsInitialized = true;

        try {
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                }
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
            SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
            System.out.println("new trust manager should be set");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

I ran the above code as part of my --before-- implementation in the test suite and verified we reached the end of the try block, so the new All_trusting TrustManager should be set.  Unfortunately this also had no effect, I am still seeing the error.

To try and isolate the issue, I processed the same POST request through both Postman and curl, both returned the desired result, no errors.

For sanity's sake I also hit a few public urls both secure and insecure and got the desired results as well.

At this point I'm stumped.  Since Postman and curl work, the error must have something to do with my implementation, but I don't understand why it would work with our old environment but not in the new one.  A debugging version of my code that makes a failing get request is below.  This fails both when run through the ide, and through the command line with maven.

Test File

```
public class DebugTests extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void debug() {
        BaseApi api = new BaseApi();
        api.debugGet("<<MYURL>>");
    }
```

BaseTest

```
@Listeners(Listener.class)
public class BaseTest {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void before() {
        // the below function is used to disable certificate validation.  It is ONLY meant to be used in testing environments
        // if used in production it exposes our test suite to MITM attacks.
        SSLTool.disableCertificateValidation();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void after() {

    }
}
```

Relevant Code from the API object

```
public BaseApi() {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLTool.disableCertificateValidation();
        client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(ctx).build();
        System.out.println("trust manager set");
    }

    public void debugGet(String endpoint) {
        try {
            client.execute(this.buildGetConnection(endpoint, false));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected HttpGet buildGetConnection(String endpoint) {
        return this.buildGetConnection(endpoint, true);
    }

    protected HttpGet buildGetConnection(String endpoint, boolean auth) {

        //TODO build a switch to change testing environments based off command line
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(rootUrl + endpoint);

        if(auth) {
            StsAuthApi authApi = new StsAuthApi();
            get.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authApi.getToken());
        }

        get.setHeader("accept","application/json");
        get.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
        System.out.println("making GET request to " + rootUrl + endpoint);
        return get;
    }
```

In my debugging implementation rooturl is an empty string so the url matches the string supplied via the test case.

Comment: updated with changes recommended by Andy, still seeing the same error

Comment: I was able to get this working by moving the code for creating the SSL context into the constructor for my base api class and removing the SSLTool class entirely.  While I am happy this works, I don't understand why!  If anyone can detail why shifting this into the constructor has made the difference, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpClients.createDefault()` will not use your null trust manager. It internally creates and initialises an `SSLContext` like this:

```
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContextBuilder.TLS);
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
```

You can create the `HttpClient` like this instead:

```
HttpClients.custom()
           .setSSLContext(ctx)
           .build();
```

Where `ctx` is the one you created in the `disableCertificateValidation()` method.

The question about why it didn't work when you added your certificate to `cacerts` is still open. If you did that correctly then the default client should have used it. You can set the system property `javax.net.debug=all` if you want to debug that one further (it will print out your truststore when it's first initialised into a context).

Comment: Thanks Andy for the response.  I'm unfortunately still seeing the same errors.  I updated my original code with the changes you suggested.  There's probably now some redundant logic in the SSL tool class, but overall I think my implementation matches your suggestion.  Let me know if I missed anything

Comment: The best clues you're going to get now are from the output of the `javax.net.debug=all` system property. It can get noisy so it's best to breakpoint just before your SSL call, clean your logs then step over the failing call, kill it and analyse the output. You should see the content of your truststore in there, and if you've added to cacerts then you should see your certificate in the output.